# How to get matched name from array key name in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Tried to get matched name from the array key name but not working. I have two array-like columns and item. I do not know how to match the array key name to column name words and assign it to the field value. If anyone knows please help to find the solutions.

```
var column = ['File Name', 'Sur Name', 'Last Name', 'Place Of Work', 'Work Id']; 
var newColumn = []; 
var item = [
    {
        fileName: 'test1',
        surName: 'test1',
        lastName: 'test1',
        placeOfWork: 'test1',
        workId: 'test1'
    }
];

column.forEach(e => {
    newColumn.push({
        label: e,
        field: function(){
            if(item.keys( e.toLowerCase() == item.keys().toLowerCase())) return item.keys(); 
        }
    });
});

console.log(newColumn);
```

Output Should be:

```
newSolumn= [
    {label:'First Name',field:'fileName'},
    {label:'Sur Name',field:'surName'}, 
    {label:'Last Name',field:'lastName'},
    {label:'Place Of Work',field:'placeOfWork'},
    {label:'Work Id',field:'workId'}
];
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-gatg4v

Comment: You are comparing the column name to the list of *all* keys, which is not valid. You have to search for the corresponding key in an inner loop/foreach. Moreover you have a space in the label, which would fail the comparison, too.

Comment: The property `field` is a function that you call. If you want it to be a string, then you don't make it a function, you just assign it to the result of your logic.

Comment: @daddygames: How to assign it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a function as a value in your created object, you need to call it instead of assigning it as a value, and you need also to remove spaces in your strings in order to compare them, I use the function replace to remove useless spaces.

```
var column = ['File Name', 'Sur Name', 'Last Name', 'Place Of Work', 'Work Id'];

var newColumn = [];

var item = [
  {
    fileName: 'test1',
    surName: 'test1',
    lastName: 'test1',
    placeOfWork: 'test1',
    workId: 'test1'
  }
];

column.forEach(e => {
  newColumn.push({
    label: e,
    field: getField(e)
  });
});

function getField(columnName) {
  for (key in item[0]) {
    if (
      columnName.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase() ===
      key.replace(/\s/g, '').toLowerCase()
    ) {
      return key;
    }
  }
}

console.log(newColumn);
```

Comment: Getting error if I use this code in typescript

Comment: Getting error like label and field is not assignable to parameter of type never

Answer (score 0):

This part is wrong:

```
field: function(){
  if(item.keys( e.toLowerCase() == item.keys().toLowerCase())) return item.keys(); 
}
```

Some issues with it:

- you don't want `field` to be a function. It should be a string value. So if there is a condition to evaluate, you should evaluate it before creating the target object, or else filter the result to remove those where the `field` could not be matched.
- `item.keys()` takes no argument, so the expression you have there will not serve any purpose. To match a property in `item`, you would better have those lower cased from the start, so you can take advantage of direct lookup. So `item` could have key/value pairs like:

  ```
    placeofwork: "placeOfWork"
  ```

  Now you can just do `item[e.toLowerCase()]`
- The spaces should be removed from `e` before you try to match.

Here is a correction:

```js
let column = ['File Name', 'Sur Name', 'Last Name', 'Place Of Work', 'Work Id'];

let item = Object.fromEntries(
    ["fileName", "surName", "lastName", "placeOfWork", "workId"].map(field => [field.toLowerCase(), field])
);

let newColumn = column.map(label => ({
    label,
    field: item[label.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, "")]
})).filter(o => o.field);

console.log(newColumn);
```